# Find $a^{b^{c}}$ given that $\frac{1}{2}{a^2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-bc-ac=2(b-1).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find $\space\large{a^{b^{c}}}$ given that $\dfrac{1}{2}{a^2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-bc-ac=2(b-1).$

Hi everyone, I attempted to apply the $(a+b+c)^{2}$ result to solve this to no avail.

For advice, please!

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{2a^2} + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ac = 2(b - 1)$ or $\frac{1}{2a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ac} = 2(b - 1)$ or something else?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I am not going to guess your problem... since for each $b,c$ there is at least one $a$ and that $a^{b^c}$ may possibly not be a fixed value...

Comment: Thanks Taussig and JetfiRex. Have updated the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Think of squares, you can get the answer.

$0=a^2/2+b^2+c^2-bc-ac-2(b-1)=(a-c)^2/2+(b-c)^2/2+(b-2)^2/2$. So you can get $a=b=c=2$ thus $a^{b^c}=16$